# What's the proper way to handle Allow and Disallow in robots.txt?

Tags: robots.txt

I run a fairly large-scale Web crawler.  We try very hard to operate the crawler within accepted community standards, and that includes respecting robots.txt.  We get very few complaints about the crawler, but when we do the majority are about our handling of robots.txt.   Most often the Webmaster made a mistake in his robots.txt and we kindly point out the error.  But periodically we run into grey areas that involve the handling of `Allow` and `Disallow`.

The [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html) page doesn't cover `Allow`.  I've seen other pages, some of which say that crawlers use a "first matching" rule, and others that don't specify.  That leads to some confusion.  For example, Google's page about robots.txt used to have this example:

```
User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow: /folder1/
Allow: /folder1/myfile.html
```

Obviously, a "first matching" rule here wouldn't work because the crawler would see the `Disallow` and go away, never crawling the file that was specifically allowed.

We're in the clear if we ignore all `Allow` lines, but then we might not crawl something that we're allowed to crawl.  We'll miss things.

We've had great success by checking `Allow` first, and then checking `Disallow`, the idea being that `Allow` was intended to be more specific than `Disallow`.  That's because, by default (i.e. in the absence of instructions to the contrary), all access is allowed.  But then we run across something like this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /norobots/
Allow: /
```

The intent here is obvious, but that `Allow: /` will cause a bot that checks `Allow` first to think it can crawl anything on the site.

Even that can be worked around in this case.  We can compare the matching `Allow` with the matching `Disallow` and determine that we're not allowed to crawl anything in /norobots/.  But that breaks down in the face of wildcards:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /norobots/
Allow: /*.html$
```

The question, then, is the bot allowed to crawl `/norobots/index.html`?

The "first matching" rule eliminates all ambiguity, but I often see sites that show something like the old Google example, putting the more specific `Allow` *after* the `Disallow`.  That syntax requires more processing by the bot and leads to ambiguities that can't be resolved.

My question, then, is what's the right way to do things?  What do Webmasters expect from a well-behaved bot when it comes to robots.txt handling?

Comment: Simply processing all the directives in order (top to bottom) would seem to remove all ambiguity (including the processing of _wildcard_ URL patterns, which is officially "undefined"). However, the main search engine bots (Googlebot, Bingbot, etc.) don't work like that, so that's not workable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One very important note: the **Allow** statement should come **before** the **Disallow** statement, no matter how specific your statements are.
So in your third example - no, the bots won't crawl `/norobots/index.html`.

Generally, as a personal rule, I put allow statements first and then I list the disallowed pages and folders.

Comment: So you're recommending that I follow "first matching rule" standard?  That is, the bot reads the robots.txt and takes the first Allow or Disallow that matches the url in question?

Comment: That's right. Like so (each one is a new line btw):
Allow /images/uploads
Allow /images/user-uploads
Disallow /images

Comment: But do you know if that's the generally accepted interpretation of robots.txt?  That is, if I were to implement the "first matching rule" standard, would that be what most Webmasters expect?

Comment: The description of Allow in the Wikipedia article on robots.txt - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard#Allow_directive - (and several other sites) says that "first matching rule" is the standard.  Since that's 100% unambiguous and easy to implement and prove correct, that's what I went with.

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question :) I wasn't sure how to respond. I don't know about the generally accepted method, however that's how I've been using it ever since I started working as a SEO expert and it has always worked correctly.

Comment: The order of Allow and Disallow statements makes no difference for Googlebot which looks at specificity instead. Bing also but don't know about other search engines so if in doubt put Allows first I guess.

Comment: This is incorrect, at least for Google. They state:
'At a group-member level, in particular for allow and disallow directives, the most specific rule based on the length of the [path] entry will trump the less specific (shorter) rule. The order of precedence for rules with wildcards is undefined'.  https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt

Best way is to test in Search Console

Comment: Whilst Google states that "The order of precedence for rules with wildcards is undefined", in my limited tests the longest path/pattern still appears to win. So, in the above example, if the directive stated: `Allow: /*ex.html$` (a pattern of 10 chars, including wildcards) then a URL of `/norobots/index.html` would be _allowed_, since this now trumps the earlier `Disallow: /norobots/` directive (also 10 chars) - in the case of a tie, _allow_ always wins.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my take on what I see in those three examples.

**Example 1**
I would ignore the entire `/folder1/` directory *except* the `myfile.html` file. Since they explicitly allow it I would assume it was simply easier to block the entire directory and explicitly allow that one file as opposed to listing every file they wanted to have blocked. If that directory contained a lot of files and subdirectories that robots.txt file could get unwieldy fast.

**Example 2**
I would assume the `/norobots/` directory is off limits and everything else is available to be crawled. I read this as "crawl everything except the /norobots/ directory".

**Example 3**
Similar to example 2, I would assume the `/norobots/` directory is off limits and all `.html` files not in that directory is available to be crawled. I read this as "crawl all .html files but do not crawl any content in the the /norobots/ directory".

Hopefully your bot's user-agent contains a URL where they can find out more information about your crawling habits and make removal requests or give you feedback about how they want their robots.txt interpreted.

Comment: Your answers probably match the intent, except for the last one, which I find somewhat questionable. In those specific cases I can code the robots handling correctly, but there are other ambiguous cases that aren't as easily determined. More, I'm looking for a general solution. And, yes, our user-agent string has a link to our FAQ page.  And although we can describe how we handle robots.txt, it'd be best for all concerned if we didn't have to. That is, if everybody handled things in the same way. But that doesn't appear to be the case.

Comment: The above is how Googlebot handles your examples as can be tested on their robots.txt testing tool (Webmaster Tools > Blocked URLs).
Google doesn't mind whether you put the Allows or Disallows first but has an algorithm that determines specificity, which leads to some not obvious results. For example, if you replace '/*.html$' with '/*myfile.html$' in the 3rd example, then 'myfile.html' is allowed rather than being blocked OR if you lose the trailing '/' from '/norobots/', .html files are also allowed.

Comment: Aha! According to Wikipedia, Google just looks at the number of characters to determine which directive to use and in the case of a 'draw' goes with 'Allow'.

Answer (score 1):

[Google expanded the documentation for robots.txt](https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_txt) for user agents that support the `Allow` directive.  The rule that Googlebot uses (and what Google is trying to make standard) is that the longest matching rule wins.

So when you have:

```
Disallow: /norobots/
Disallow: /nobot/
Allow:    /*.html$
Allow:    /****.gif$
```

- `/norobots/index.html` is **blocked** because it matches two rules and `/norobots/` is longer (10 characters) than `/*.html$` (8 characters).
- `/nobot/index.html` is **allowed** because it matches two rules and `/nobot/` is shorter (7 characters) than `/*.html$` (8 characters).
- `/norobots/pic.gif` is **allowed** because it matches two rules and `/norobots/` is equal length (10 characters) to `/****.gif$` (10 characters).  Google's spec says that the "less restrictive" rule should be used for rules of equal length, ie. the one that allows crawling.

Comment: I think Google's spec is a bit ambiguous...  "In case of conflicting rules, **including those with wildcards**, the least restrictive rule is used." (previously Google has always stated that the precedence of rules with wildcards was "undefined"). I take that to mean any "wildcard" rule, regardless of length. However, in the case of wildcards, the longest matching rule still appears to win. A more specific `Disallow` rule with wildcards still wins over a shorter `Allow` rule with wildcards.

Comment: `/****.gif$` - it gets a bit "confusing" when using multiple adjacent wildcards since `*` matches "0 or more" anyway, so `/****.gif$` is really the same as `/*.gif$` - however, it appears to have different precedence.

Comment: Yeah the multiple stars are there just to increase the length of the rule and it's precedence.