# Robots.txt with only Disallow and Allow directives is not preventing crawling of disallowed resources

Tags: web-crawlers, robots.txt

I have a `robots.txt` file:

```
User-agent:*
Disallow:/path/page
Disallow:/path/
Allow:/
```

The disallowed path is still getting crawled.

I have searched this problem and what they said, order of precedence in google does not matter. So technically, the disallowed should work but now I'm wondering if it is because `Allow:/` is overriding it?

Comment: http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html You do not have an agents directive. As well, you do not have to specify what you *allow*, but do have to specify what you *disallow*.

Comment: Sorry I didn't put it there but yes I do have User-agent:*. Yes I was wondering about that. I know by default, all web-crawlers are allowed. I think what was happening is that because I have "Allow:/", it's like overwriting it? Is this correct?

Comment: "order of precedence in google does not matter" - you mean the "order of the _directives_ does not matter". There is always an order of precedence (unless you are using "wildcards", in which case it is officially "undefined").

Comment: As others have stated, you don't _need_ the `Allow:` directive, but neither should this be causing problems. The other "disallowed" URLs should still be blocked regardless of whether the `Allow:` directive is present or not. What does GSC report? When did you make this change? Do you have other directives in your robots.txt file? You've presumably confirmed from your logs that Googlebot is still crawling these URLs?

Answer (score 5):

Putting your page through [Google's *robots.txt* tester](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062598?hl=en&ref_topic=6061961) reveals two problems:

1. You have no `User-agent` line so your rules don't apply to *any* crawler:  [image]
2. Once you put in the `User-agent` line, the `Allow` line overrides the disallow: [image]

The correct robots.txt file would be:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /path/page
Disallow: /path/
```

**DO NOT** use `Allow:`.   Allowing crawling is the default.   You only need to include the items you *don't* want crawled.

Include the `User-Agent:` line to specify that it applies to all crawlers.   Otherwise, it will apply to none.

I don't think that having a space after the colon actually matters, but all the examples I see have it.

I should also add that *robots.txt* is only for crawlers that choose to obey it.  Search engine spiders like Googlebot should obey *robots.txt*, however not all other spiders will.

Comment: "page/path" - You seem to be testing the wrong URL-path. If you tested "/path/page" as stated in the `Disallow` directive then this should be "BLOCKED" - since the _most specific rule_ should win.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned, the `Allow:` directive in this instance is superfluous. The default action is to allow all crawling, so explicitly stating `Allow: /` (ie. allow all) is entirely redundant.

However, contrary to what has been suggested, neither would the `Allow: /` directive cause you any problems. The `Allow: /` directive will not "override" other `Disallow:` directives, because it is the least specific, regardless of the apparent *order*.

> order of precedence in google does not matter.

Yes, sort of. You mean the "order of the *directives* does not matter". There is always an order of precedence (unless you are using "wildcards", in which case it is officially "undefined"). This is why the `Allow: /` directive does not override the more *specific* `Disallow:` directives above it. [Google defines the order of precedence](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt#order-of-precedence-for-group-member-records):

> for allow and disallow directives, **the most specific rule based on the length of the [path] entry will trump the less specific (shorter) rule**.

And this is confirmed by using [Google's robots.txt Tester](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062598?hl=en&ref_topic=6061961), when testing a disallowed path eg. `/path/page`:

[image: Google's robot.txt Tester - Disallow]

This is at least how Googlebot and Bingbot work (the most specific path wins). However, some (old) bots reportedly use a "first match" rule. So, for greatest compatibility it is recommended to include any `Allow:` directives first. Reference: [What's the proper way to handle Allow and Disallow in robots.txt?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6172/whats-the-proper-way-to-handle-allow-and-disallow-in-robots-txt)

Also, since robots.txt is *prefix matching*, the `Disallow: /path/page` directive is also superfluous, since `Disallow: /path/` will block `/path/page` as well. So, in summary, your `robots.txt` file only *needs* the one `Disallow` directive, the others are simply superfluous but will not actually cause any harm:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /path/
```

White space before the *path* is entirely optional, although as noted in Stephen's answer, it is much more common to see it and it arguably makes it more readable.

The only time you would *need* an `Allow:` directive is if you need to make an exception and allow a URL that would otherwise be blocked by a `Disallow:` directive. eg. If you wanted to allow `/path/foo` in the above `robots.txt` file then you would need to explicitly include the `Allow: /path/foo` directive *somewhere* in the group.

> The disallowed path is still getting crawled.

If this is still the case, then something else is going on...

- Do you have any other directives in your `robots.txt` file. Test the URL in Google's robot.txt Tester.
- When was the current `robots.txt` file implemented? Google only picks up changes to the `robots.txt` file every day or so. In GSC you can identify which version Googlebot is currently using.
- As Stephen has already pointed out, `robots.txt` is only honoured by the "good bots". Many (bad) bots will simply ignore it and crawl your URLs regardless. You can check in your access logs as to whether the "good" bots are still crawling these disallowed URLs.

Comment: I see what you mean in your comment.  I had elements in the path mixed up.   Thank you for posting your own answer addressing it further.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller There seems to be _something_ about "/path/page" that makes it easy to type the wrong way round (in a tongue twister sort of way?) - I initially typed it the wrong way round a couple of times as well!?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your question what kind of site you have. If it is a SPA, it would explain the problems that you are having. robots.txt does not seem to deal effectively with SPA's and other solutions need to be looked for.